# Matching only one occurrence of a character from a given set

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate an input string such that validation returns `true` only if the string contains one of the special characters @ # $ %, only one, and one time at the most. Letters and numbers can be anywhere and can be repeated any number of times, but at least one number or letter should be present

For example:

a@ : true

@a : true

a@$: false

a@n01 : true

an01 : false

a : false

@ : false

I tried

```
 [0-9A-Za-z]*[@#%$]{1}[0-9A-Za-z]*
```

I was hoping this would match one occurrence of any of the special characters. But, no. I need only one occurrence of any one in the set.

I also tried alternation but could not solve it.

Comment: @zx81 answers the question, but as additional info your regex was failing because it matched `a@` in `a@$`, so returned as having found something. Anchors `^$` will indeed solve that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vivek, your regex was really close. Here is the one-line regex you are looking for.

```
^(?=.*?[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]*[@#$%][0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jA0zR4)

**How does it work?**

1. The `^` and `$` anchors ensure that whatever we are matching is the whole string, avoiding partial matches with forbidden characters later.
2. The `(?=.*?[0-9a-zA-Z])` lookahead ensures that we have at least one number or letter.
3. The `[0-9a-zA-Z]*[@#$%][0-9a-zA-Z]*` matches zero or more letters or digits, followed by exactly **one** character that is either a `@`, `#`, `$` or `%`, followed by zero or more letters or digits—ensuring that we have one special character but no more.

**Implementation**

I am sure you know how to implement this in Java, but to test if the string match, you could use something like this:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("^(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]*[@#$%][0-9a-zA-Z]*$)[@#$%0-9a-zA-Z]*");
```

**What was wrong with my regex?**

Actually, your regex was nearly there. Here is what was missing.

1. Because you didn't have the `^` and `$` anchors, the regex was able to match a subset of the string, for instance `a#` in `a##%%`, which means that special characters could appear in the string, but outside of the match. Not what you want: we need to validate the whole string by anchoring it.
2. You needed something to ensure that at least one letter or digit was present. You could definitely have done it with an alternation, but in this case a lookahead is more compact.

**Alternative with Alternation**

Since you tried alternations, for the record, here is one way to do it:

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+[@#$%][0-9a-zA-Z]*|[0-9a-zA-Z]*[@#$%][0-9a-zA-Z]+)$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ1cE3).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Why do you need the ending (`[@#$%0-9a-zA-Z]*`) part?

Comment: @GáborBakos I was in the process of adjusting as you wrote. It now has one lookahead, and one matching part.

Comment: @zx81 Can you explain this. How it works.The lookahead (?=.*?[0-9a-zA-Z])

Comment: @VivekVardhan `(?=` means `assert that at this position we can match...` match what? Match `.*?[0-9a-zA-Z]` which means any number of characters `.*` followed by `[0-9a-zA-Z]` one letter or digit. The  `?` in `.*?` makes the quantifier lazy, affecting the backtracking—not important in your regex, it will work with or without it. I believe your next stop on your course for world regex domination is [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: The ^ and $ anchors ensure that whatever we are matching is the whole string, avoiding partial matches with forbidden characters later. It took me 3 hours to understand it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer will be useful for you, if not, it might be for future readers. I am going to make two assumptions here up front: 1) You do not need regex per se, you are programming in Java. 2) You have access to Java 8.

This could be done the following way:

```
private boolean stringMatchesChars(final String str, final List<Character> characters) {
    return (str.chars()
            .filter(ch -> characters.contains((char)ch))
            .count() == 1);
}
```

Here I am:

1. Using as input a `String` and a `List<Character>` of the ones that are allowed.
2. Obtaining an `IntStream` (consisting of chars) from the `String`.
3. Filtering every `char` to only remain in the stream if they are in the `List<Character>`.
4. Return `true` only if the `count() == 1`, that is of the characters in `List<Character>`, exactly one is present.

The code can be used as:

```
String str1 = "a";
String str2 = "a@";
String str3 = "a@@a";
String str4 = "a#@a";
List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList('@', '#', '$', '%');

System.out.println("stringMatchesChars(str1, characters) = " + stringMatchesChars(str1, characters));
System.out.println("stringMatchesChars(str2, characters) = " + stringMatchesChars(str2, characters));
System.out.println("stringMatchesChars(str3, characters) = " + stringMatchesChars(str3, characters));
System.out.println("stringMatchesChars(str4, characters) = " + stringMatchesChars(str4, characters));
```

Resulting in `false`, `true`, `false`, `false`.